# Filter two column array based on common values in one column

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I'm ultimately trying to create a list of all of the teams that share 1-5 common selected players.  If only one player is selected, then all of the teams that player is on will appear.  But if 2 or more players are selected, then all players would need to have a common team for it to be displayed.  If only 2 out of 3 players share a team, it wouldn't appear.

I can filter my list to my selected players and what teams they're on, but then, I want to narrow that down to only the teams they have in common with each other.  The player doesn't need to be displayed, I just have it displayed to better understand what data I'm seeing.

If my search criteria is:

```
Player 1
Player 2
Player 3
```

Using this formula...

```excel
=FILTER({data!C2:C,data!B2:B},COUNTIF(A2:A6,data!C2:C))
```

I get...

```
Player 1    Team A
Player 2    Team A
Player 3    Team A
Player 1    Team B
Player 3    Team B
Player 2    Team C
Player 3    Team C
Player 2    Team D
Player 2    Team E
Player 3    Team E
Player 1    Team E
```

I then want to find the common teams. So...

```
Player 1    Team A
Player 1    Team E
Player 2    Team A
Player 2    Team E
Player 3    Team A
Player 3    Team E
```

I thought something like *this* would work

```excel
=FILTER({data!C2:C,data!B2:B},
  COUNTIF(A2,data!C2:C),
  COUNTIF(A3,data!C2:C),
  COUNTIF(A4,data!C2:C),
  COUNTIF(A5,data!C2:C),
  COUNTIF(A6,data!C2:C)
)
```

I've been staring at this until I feel crosseyed and it may be something simple that I'm just overlooking, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Here is [my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LHTyxPbjcSwCAoHA1Sf4ROW9L33hQhqmQnwNpiFiiAI/edit#gid=0&range=A2) if anyone would care to have a look.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could explain your desired result a bit better. I don't understand your results currently and why team C and E are excluded for example.

Comment: You're right.  I didn't explain myself very well and I forgot to include the criteria I was using to get the results in my example.  Luckily, @kishkin was able to figure out what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this one suit you?

```
=FILTER(
  FILTER(
    {data!C2:C, data!B2:B},
    IFNA(MATCH(data!C2:C, A2:A6, 0))
  ),
  COUNTIF(
    FILTER(
      data!B2:B,
      IFNA(MATCH(data!C2:C, A2:A6, 0))
    ),
    FILTER(
      data!B2:B,
      IFNA(MATCH(data!C2:C, A2:A6, 0))
    )
  ) = COUNTA(A2:A6)
)
```

The `FILTER` part:

[image]

Sure it is possible to make a similar solution on encapsulated `QUERY`s.